# action bar button not opening drawer

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-actionbar

I have a fragment activity with an actionbar that should open the navbar when you click the home screen icon with the three line icon that represents the drawer opening for android.

For some reason, I can click the button but its not opening the drawer... I can open the drawer by using the sliding gesture...

```
public class MainDrawer2 extends FragmentActivity
{
    private static final String EXTRA_NAV_ITEM    = "extraNavItem";
    private static final String STATE_CURRENT_NAV = "stateCurrentNav";

    private ActionBarDrawerToggle mDrawerToggle;
    private DrawerLayout mDrawerLayout;

    private NavDrawerListAdapter mDrawerAdapter;
    private ListView mDrawerList;

    private CharSequence mTitle;
    private CharSequence mDrawerTitle;

    private MainNavItem mCurrentNavItem;


    public static Intent createLaunchFragmentIntent(Context context, MainNavItem navItem)
    {
        return new Intent(context, MainDrawer2.class)
                .putExtra(EXTRA_NAV_ITEM, navItem.ordinal());
    }

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.fragment_main);

        mTitle = mDrawerTitle = getTitle();
        mDrawerLayout = (DrawerLayout)findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        mDrawerList   = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.drawer);

        getActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
        enableHomeButtonIfRequired();

        mDrawerAdapter = new NavDrawerListAdapter(getApplicationContext());
        mDrawerList.setAdapter(mDrawerAdapter);
        mDrawerList.setOnItemClickListener(new ListView.OnItemClickListener()
        {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id)
            {
                displayNavFragment((MainNavItem)parent.getItemAtPosition(position));
            }
        });

        mDrawerToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(this, mDrawerLayout,
                R.drawable.ic_drawer, R.string.app_name, R.string.app_name)
        {
            public void onDrawerClosed(View view)
            {
                getActionBar().setTitle(mTitle);
                invalidateOptionsMenu();
            }

            public void onDrawerOpened(View drawerView)
            {
                getActionBar().setTitle(mDrawerTitle);
                invalidateOptionsMenu();
            }
        };

        mDrawerLayout.setDrawerListener(mDrawerToggle);

        if(getIntent().hasExtra(EXTRA_NAV_ITEM)){
            MainNavItem navItem = MainNavItem.values()
                    [getIntent().getIntExtra(EXTRA_NAV_ITEM,
                    MainNavItem.STATISTICS.ordinal())];
            displayNavFragment(navItem);
        }
        else if(savedInstanceState != null){
            mCurrentNavItem = MainNavItem.values()
                    [savedInstanceState.getInt(STATE_CURRENT_NAV)];
            setCurrentNavItem(mCurrentNavItem);
        }
        else{
            displayNavFragment(MainNavItem.STATISTICS);
        }
    }

    @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.ICE_CREAM_SANDWICH)
    private void enableHomeButtonIfRequired()
    {
        if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.ICE_CREAM_SANDWICH){
            getActionBar().setHomeButtonEnabled(true);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void setTitle(CharSequence title)
    {
        mTitle = title;
        getActionBar().setTitle(mTitle);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onPostCreate(savedInstanceState);
        // Sync the toggle state after onRestoreInstanceState has occurred.
        mDrawerToggle.syncState();
    }

    @Override
    public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig)
    {
        super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
        // Pass any configuration change to the drawer toggles
        mDrawerToggle.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState)
    {
        super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
        outState.putInt(STATE_CURRENT_NAV, mCurrentNavItem.ordinal());
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu)
    {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    /*
    @Override
    public boolean onPrepareOptionsMenu(Menu menu)
    {
        // if nav drawer is opened, hide the action items
        boolean drawerOpen = mDrawerLayout.isDrawerOpen(mDrawerList);
        menu.findItem(R.id.action_settings).setVisible(!drawerOpen);
        return super.onPrepareOptionsMenu(menu);
    }
    */



    private void displayNavFragment(MainNavItem navItem)
    {
        if(navItem == mCurrentNavItem){
            return;
        }
        Fragment fragment = Fragment.instantiate(this,
                navItem.getFragClass().getName());
        if(fragment != null){
            getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                    .replace(R.id.main, fragment)
                    .commit();
            setCurrentNavItem(navItem);
        }
    }

    private void setCurrentNavItem(MainNavItem navItem)
    {
        int position = navItem.ordinal();
        // If navItem is in DrawerAdapter
        if(position >= 0 && position < mDrawerAdapter.getCount()){
            mDrawerList.setItemChecked(position, true);
        }
        else{
            // navItem not in DrawerAdapter, de-select current item
            if(mCurrentNavItem != null){
                mDrawerList.setItemChecked(mCurrentNavItem.ordinal(), false);
            }
        }
        mDrawerLayout.closeDrawer(mDrawerList);
        setTitle(navItem.getTitleResId());
        mCurrentNavItem = navItem;
    }




    public void goToSearch(MenuItem item){

        //go to search page
        Fragment Fragment_one;
        FragmentManager man= getSupportFragmentManager();
        FragmentTransaction tran = man.beginTransaction();
        Fragment_one = new Search();

        tran.replace(R.id.main, Fragment_one);//tran.
        tran.addToBackStack(null);
        tran.commit();

    }



}
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You need to explicitly define this action, it is not provided automatically by the nav drawer API. Add the following to your activity:

```
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
    case android.R.id.home:
        if(mDrawerLayout.isDrawerOpen(drawerList)) {
            mDrawerLayout.closeDrawer(drawerList);
        }
        else {
            mDrawerLayout.openDrawer(drawerList);
        }
        return true;
    default:
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

**So much struggle for changing hamburger icon with back arrow. I gone through many posts but every post was missing something Finally i handled this way -**

**Put this code inside Activity -**

```
private void setupNavigationDrawer() {
        mDrawerToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(
                this, mDrawer, R.string.navigation_drawer_open, R.string.navigation_drawer_close);
        mDrawer.addDrawerListener(mDrawerToggle);
        navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);
        if (getSupportActionBar() != null) {
            getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
            getSupportActionBar().setHomeButtonEnabled(true);
        }
        setDrawerState(true);
    }

    public void setDrawerState(boolean isEnabled) {
        if (isEnabled) {
            mDrawer.setDrawerLockMode(DrawerLayout.LOCK_MODE_UNLOCKED, GravityCompat.START);
            mDrawerToggle.syncState();
        } else {
            mDrawer.setDrawerLockMode(DrawerLayout.LOCK_MODE_LOCKED_CLOSED, GravityCompat.START);
            //Drawable backButton = ContextCompat.getDrawable(this, R.mipmap.ic_back_button);
            getSupportActionBar().setHomeAsUpIndicator(null);
        }
    }

@Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        int id = item.getItemId();
        if (id == android.R.id.home) {
            if (mDrawer.getDrawerLockMode(GravityCompat.START) == DrawerLayout.LOCK_MODE_LOCKED_CLOSED) {
                onBackPressed();
            } else {
                drawerToggle();
            }
            return true;
        } else if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    private void drawerToggle() {
        if (mDrawer.isDrawerVisible(GravityCompat.START)) {
            mDrawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
        } else {
            mDrawer.openDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
        }
    }
```

**Put this inside your fragment**

```
public void onActivityCreated(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
        if (getActivity() != null) {
            ((DashboardActivity) getActivity()).setDrawerState(false);
        }
    }

@Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        if (getActivity() != null) {
            ((DashboardActivity) getActivity()).setDrawerState(true);
        }
    }
```

**Please correct me if i am wrong at anyplace.**